# RShiny Error: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm getting the following error:

```
 "The following error happened while the function call GetForwardProduct():\n Error in 
.getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext(): Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
 (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)\n"
```

My **UI** looks like this:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

                 dateRangeInput(inputId = "maSpreadDateRange", label = "Select Date Range", 
                                start = "2016-01-01", end = Sys.Date()),
                 selectInput(inputId = "maCommodity2", label = "Select Commodity", 
                             choices = c("Power", "Gas", "Oil", "Coal", "CO2", "EUR/USD")),
                 uiOutput(outputId = "maOutputMarketArea2"),
                 uiOutput(outputId = "maOutputBasePeak2"),
                 textInput(inputId = "maProd2", label = "Define Forward Product", value = "Cal-2021"),
                 actionButton(inputId = "goSpread", label = "Calculate")
                 
))
```

My **server**:

```
shinyServer(
function(input, output) {

  # Dynamical input selection for market area 2: #
  output$maOutputMarketArea2 <- renderUI({
    
    try({
      
      commodity <- input$maCommodity2
      
      if (commodity == "Power"){
          selectInput(inputId = "maMarketArea2", label = "Select Market Area", choices = c("DE", "AT"))
      } else if (commodity == "Gas"){
          selectInput(inputId = "maMarketArea2", label = "Select Market Area", choices = c("TTF", "NCG", "CEGH VTP"))
      } 
      
    })
    
  })
  
  # Dynamical input selection for base or peak 1: #
  output$maOutputBasePeak2 <- renderUI({
    
    try({
      
      commodity <- input$maCommodity2
      
      if (commodity == "Power"){
          selectInput(inputId = "maBasePeak2", label = "Select Base or Peak", choices = c("Base", "Peak"))
      }
      
    })
    
  })
  
  # Reactive expression for product 2 function call: #
  comm <- input$maCommodity2
  marketA <- input$maMarketArea2
  baseP <- input$maBasePeak2

      maProduct2 <- reactive({
        maProduct2 <- GetForwardProduct(commodity = comm, marketArea = marketA, basePeak = baseP, 
                                        product = input$maProd2)
      })
```

I don't know how to use the reactive expression, I'm very new to RShiny! The function `GetForwardProduct()` in the `reactive({  })` is a function that merges strings together.
The function `MASpread()` works fince, but not with the reactive expression. Can someone help me??

Comment: Don't create the variables `comm`, `marketA` and `baseP` outside of your reactive, but just use `input$maCommodity2` and so on in the reactive directly in the `GetForwardProduct` call. The `input` variables are reactive values which you call in the `server`, which is not a reactive environment

Comment: @starja thank you, now the Error with the reactive value isn't displayed anymore! But there are so many other errors and warnings.....

Comment: Try to understand the error messages and google them; I also recommend to read a [shiny tutorial](https://mastering-shiny.org)

Comment: The problem is, that ```print(maProduct2)``` gives nothing. So something doesn't work with the ```reactive({})``` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remember that *input* should be wrapped inside a reactive and a reactive should be associated with (). For example, I am slightly rewriting your code in a form that it works and prints the text with the input that the user selects. I wrapped the *maProduct2* inside a reactive and print that reactive using *renderText* and verbatimTextOutput as can be seen below. I don't know what your **getForwardProduct()** function does so I simply used paste() to illustrate below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput(
    inputId = "maSpreadDateRange",
    label = "Select Date Range",
    start = "2016-01-01",
    end = Sys.Date()
  ),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "maCommodity2",
    label = "Select Commodity",
    choices = c("Power", "Gas", "Oil", "Coal", "CO2", "EUR/USD")
  ),
  uiOutput(outputId = "maOutputMarketArea2"),
  uiOutput(outputId = "maOutputBasePeak2"),
  textInput(
    inputId = "maProd2",
    label = "Define Forward Product",
    value = "Cal-2021"
  ),
  actionButton(inputId = "goSpread", label = "Calculate"),
  

  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Dynamical input selection for market area 2: #
  output$maOutputMarketArea2 <- renderUI({
    try({
      commodity <- input$maCommodity2
      
      if (commodity == "Power") {
        selectInput(
          inputId = "maMarketArea2",
          label = "Select Market Area",
          choices = c("DE", "AT")
        )
      } else if (commodity == "Gas") {
        selectInput(
          inputId = "maMarketArea2",
          label = "Select Market Area",
          choices = c("TTF", "NCG", "CEGH VTP")
        )
      }
      
    })
    
  })
  
  # Dynamical input selection for base or peak 1: #
  output$maOutputBasePeak2 <- renderUI({
    try({
      commodity <- input$maCommodity2
      
      if (commodity == "Power") {
        selectInput(
          inputId = "maBasePeak2",
          label = "Select Base or Peak",
          choices = c("Base", "Peak")
        )
      }
      
    })
    
  })
  

  maProduct2 <- reactive({
    paste(input$maCommodity2,
          input$maBasePeak2,
          input$maProd2)
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    maProduct2()
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```